# how to set SO_REUSEADDR on the socket used by QTcpServer?

Tags: qt, sockets, qtcpserver

I have been using a QTcpServer subclass as a http server, but now I need to reuse the server port.

I have tried to set `ShareAddress | ReuseAddressHint` in a QTcpSocket, it seems worked, because the same port can be bound twice. But I did not find a way to get a QTcpSocket object from an existing QTcpServer object.

I also used the `socketDescriptor()` to get the native socket, because I want to use the linux C way to `setsockopt`, but I don't know how to use linux C code with Qt code together to set socket options.(I followed the Qt style until now.)

I am on ubuntu and Qt5.4. And I am stuck...
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because **[SO_REUSEPORT](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)** needs to be set before **bind**/**listen** is called you need to create descriptor first, set all needed flags, bind, listen and forward your descriptor to *[QTcpServer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html)* for future usage with it.

Here is an example which will listen on port 9999 on any interface

**mytcpserver.h**:

```
#ifndef MYTCPSERVER_H
#define MYTCPSERVER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QTcpServer>

class MyTcpServer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyTcpServer(QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void newConnection();

private:
    QTcpServer *server;
};

#endif // MYTCPSERVER_H
```

**mytcpserver.cpp**:

```
#include "mytcpserver.h"
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

MyTcpServer::MyTcpServer(QObject *parent):QObject(parent)
{
    this->server = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(server, &QTcpServer::newConnection, this, &MyTcpServer::newConnection);

    // open server and listen on given port
    int sockfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR: IoT Omega Daemon can't open socket";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int flag = 1;
    if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &flag, sizeof(int)) == -1)
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR: Can't set SO_REUSEADDR";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //set Address,IFace, Port...
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(9999);


    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) < 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR: can't bind socket";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(listen(sockfd,SOMAXCONN) < 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR: can't listen on port";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //forward our descriptor with SO_REUSEPORT to QTcpServer member
    server->setSocketDescriptor(sockfd);
}

void MyTcpServer::newConnection()
{
    qDebug() << "NEW CONNECTION " << __LINE__;

    QTcpSocket * socket = server->nextPendingConnection();

    socket->write("Hello client\r\n");
    socket->flush();
    socket->waitForBytesWritten(3000);

    socket->close();
}
```

Maybe you would like to optimize your socket usage even more? For example setting **SO_LINGER** timeout of zero to avoid large numbers of connections sitting in the **TIME_WAIT** state? Maybe you don't ned waiting for ACKs(**TCP_NODELAY**)?

Then your newConnection function can look like this:

```
void MyTcpServer::newConnection()
{
    qDebug() << "NEW CONNECTION " << __LINE__;

    QTcpSocket * socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
    int flag = 1;
    struct linger l = {1,0};

    if(setsockopt(socket->socketDescriptor(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char *)&flag, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR: Can't set SO_REUSEADDR";
    }

    if(setsockopt(socket->socketDescriptor(), IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &flag, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR: can't fork set TCP_NODELAY";
    }

    socket->write("Hello client\r\n");
    socket->flush();
    socket->waitForBytesWritten(3000);

    if(setsockopt(socket->socketDescriptor(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (const char *)&l,sizeof(l)) < 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR: Can't set SO_LINGER";
    }

    socket->close();
}
```

This will just do the job and free any used socket resource so they can be reused just right after that. Usefull for heavyload microservers, etc..

Comment: You saved me. After I added `setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &flag, sizeof(int))`, I can rebind the same port in other socket.